# Testing JavaScript without the codebase

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, jasmine, bdd

I know it is a weird question, but wanted clarification nevertheless.

Assume there is an application and the testing team has access to this application only through a URL, with no access to the codebase. 
My question is, can one write say jasmine test cases without access to a code base by only using the URL.

PS: My opinion is that it is not possible, because I think it doesn't fit the idea behind which most of these testing frameworks are created.

Comment: Depends on what you're testing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is dependent on the system in question, about which we know nothing.

Comment: It would mostly be regression testing.

Comment: Perhaps [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (which tests *end-user interactions*) would be more appropriate than a *unit-testing* framework like Jasmine? By vary nature, unit-testing frameworks generally require close(r) coupling with - and consistent access to - the specific methods being tested.

Comment: @user2864740 They already have a Selenium test suite in place.

Comment: @MikeW I'm just trying to get an idea of whether or not this kind of a scenario is possible, considering as pointed out in the PS, jasmine and most other frameworks are created with the idea of doing TDD or BDD. For both the cases the team would have access to the codebase.

Even for an existing app they would still have the codebase, to write the tests for.

Comment: @Phoenix Regression testing *what*? The JS code? You have access to the JS code, but are at the mercy of how it's delivered to you, e.g., it could be obfuscated or minimized. The application? That's integration/functional testing, e.g., Selenium or similar. What are you trying to test?

Comment: @DaveNewton The code is minified and uglified.

Comment: @Phoenix **What are you trying to test?** Trying to test JS that you don't have the code for seems really, really silly, and it doesn't make any sense. You really can't do that in any reasonable way, nor does it make sense that you'd be expected to. Test system behavior.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I need to tell the test team, just needed to see the bigger picture. :)

Answer (score 1):

When accessing the app by URL, does the team have any access to inputs/controls of the app? If so, they can write test cases using something like SilkTest instead. I haven't used Jasmine, but it looks as if it tests actual code itself, rather than doing automated testing on the app as if it were a user. In that case, if your code on the URL is obfuscated or encrypted, then no, they can't test it. If it's plain Javascript code, then they can see it all right in the browser, and write test cases based on that.

Comment: Isn't that more or less like having Selenium tests ??

Comment: Yeah, both operate through the user interface. If you're looking to unit-test the app, it's possible by copy-pasting the code and studying it like that. Are your .js files encrypted or minified? If there is no special obscurement in place, then they can see the source code right through their own browser.

Comment: The is minified and uglified :)

Comment: Then I think they could still test the code itself, if they have access to all the relevant function documentation. If all they see is client-end uglified code, then no, they can't know which functions to call and what values to check. But if they know what to look for, they can absolutely write test cases that will run on uglified code.